# Contactless Java Card stuck in unusable state. How to recover?

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard, javacard, contactless-smartcard

A contactless Java Card was removed from the reader before the transaction was finished (the specific case is an Android app called OpenKeychain accessing a PGP applet) and got stuck into an unusable state:

- Android NFC apps cannot access the card. The sound made by the phone is different than the one made when tapping a valid card.
- When using a contactless reader connected to a laptop, PCSC returns

  `sun.security.smartcardio.PCSCException: SCARD_E_NOT_TRANSACTED`
- Other tools such as GPShell cannot access the card either.

The card still sends an ATS when powered up.

Do you know of any low-level command that can be used to "reset" the card? (the analogy being the reset button that restarts a computer). Or is it truly unrecoverable?
An ideal solution would be one implementable on Android, given the wide availability of terminals usable as NFC readers.

Comment: I have some similar experiences with two contact card. The solution for me was keeping the card in the card reader for 10-20 minutes idle! So, you can trying to put the card in the field of your contact-less reader for a 10-20 minutes time and after that try to send  commands.

Comment: I left it on top of a contactless reader for a long time, but it didn't work: maybe the reader only powers the field when sending/receiving commands. Maybe I should write a script that forces it to power the field for a long time...

Comment: Is this a contactless-only card or a dual interface card?

Comment: It is a contactless-only card.

Comment: From my personal experience with some JCOP cards, I only managed to recover them through the contact interface.